# Localization in an iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I am trying to localize my iOS app. However, I do not have translations for all the languages supported by Apple. I have translations for French and Dutch, with English as the base language. I wanted to know the common behavior in the following scenario.
Suppose I set the iPhone language to French and then navigate to the app. I am able to correctly see all the translations.
Now, I set the iPhone language to Portuguese. Now when I navigate to the app and I see the translations are still in French and not in English (the base language of my app).
Is this behavior right? Shouldn't the language be set to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language fallback is in the Settings app.  It defaults to languages the user has set the phone to in the past -- they can change it in iOS 9.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.